# How can I configure vscode to go to the source code of an imported component in a project created in PHPstorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem opening the source code of a component using ctrl + leftClick on a variable. The project was previously developed in phpstorm. The action ctrl + leftClick does not open the file but shows where it is used in this file.

[This is what the file looks like in which I want to go to the source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtvOB.png)

[This is what the "conf" folder looks like with index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzrWV.png)

[This is what the index.js file looks like in the "AccountingDocumentsConf" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzvVy.png)

[Here is also jsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bI6a.png)

It is necessary that the source file opens with this action